# foo:FooBar = e.target of MouseEvent?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have many different Units on a map and I want to discover which one has been clicked by the mouse.  I want to do something like this:

```
private function setupUnit(gridx:uint, gridy:uint):void {
    unit = new Unit(gridx, gridy);
    unit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onUnitClick);
}

private function onUnitClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    active_unit:Unit = e.target;
}
```

And later use active_unit.method().  But this throws the error "Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Unit"

I'm sure there's a super simple way to do this =P.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast the value to the right type or use the `as` keyword.
The cast will raise a runtime exception if it's not the right type, and the `as` keyword will return null:

```
var active_unit:Unit=Unit(e.target);
// or
var active_unit:Unit=e.target as Unit;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I wasn't sure what to even search for, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
private function setupUnit(gridx:uint, gridy:uint):void {
    unit = new Unit(gridx, gridy);
    unit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onUnitClick);
}

private function onUnitClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    active_unit:Unit = e.target as Unit;

    if (active_unit:Unit) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

do?  You need the `if` because `as` will return a `null` if there is a type mismatch.

You can also use

```
active_unit:Unit = Unit(e.target);
```

but that can throw an exception if there is a type mismatch.

IIRC, there are a bunch of questions here about casting versus just using `as`.